# How to construct IEnumerable from a list of lambda expression in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

In a `C#` project, I want to be able to create a function that accepts an `IQuereable<User>` object along with multiple lambda's expressions then converts it into a different object. However, instead of pulling all the available properties from the database, I want to pull only the properties that are provided to the function. Here is the logic that I think I need to follow

1. Figure out what properties that I need to select
2. Construct an IEnumerable from the IQueryable by specifying which properties that are needed.
3. Iterate over every property that was selected and create the `Student` object.

In other words, if I call `.ToList()` on the `IQuereable<User> users` object, the query will select `*` from the databse table which pull all available columns. Instead I want to select only the properties that are passed as labda expressions.

Here is my code

```
public IEnumerable<Student> Make(IQuereable<User> users, Expression<Func<User, dynamic>> keyProperty, params Expression<Func<User, dynamic>>[] propertiesToSelect)
{
    var students = new List<Student>();

    // Make a distinct list of lambda's expressions that I need to select
    var props = propertiesToSelect.ToList();
    props.Add(keyProperty);

    props = props.Distinct().ToList();

    // TO DO!!! Some how, I need to only select the properties that are in **props** array insted of pulling all available properties
    var selectableUsers = users.Select(/**/).ToList();

    foreach(var user in selectableUsers)
    {
        var student = new Student();

        foreach(Expression<Func<User, object> exp in props)
        {
            var prop = GetPropertyInfo(user, exp)
            object value = prop.GetValue(user, null);
            // Set the property student property
            // Do somthing with prop.Name...
            // Do something with value...
        }

        students.Add(student);
    }

    return strudents;
}
```

**Question** How can I use LINQ to select only the list of Expressions

Comment: Is this a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744055/pass-in-an-expression-to-linqs-select

Comment: You could make the method generic and have an `Expression<Func<User, T>>` that creates an anonymous class of the properties you want and then also pass in a `Func<T, Student>` that will create a `Student` from them.

Comment: It would be helpfull if you post `User` and `Student` clasees. Also, does your `keyProperty` used to filter `User` collection?

Comment: Please show an example of calling your function and the kind of lambda's you want to pass in the array.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a case for using a stored procedure and dynamic SQL to build your initial query and control the contents of the SELECT statement.

The other option I see is to define a DTO object and leverage the AutoMapper Queryable Extensions and use the [Explicit Expansion](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#explicit-expansion) functionality to control the data to return.